# use Effect dependency warning on mounting

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I just want to use `useEffect` for once on page render but it gives me a warning about adding `todos` as a parameter to my `effect`, if I do that it will run every single time when the `todos` state is changing.
how can I solve that?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify([]));
    } else {
      let localTodos = localStorage.getItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
      console.log(localTodos);
    }
  }, []);
```

[image]

Comment: What gives a warning? Could u show the warning message?

Comment: @Stanley edited my question. now you can see the picture

Comment: Why don't you want it to run every time todos changes? Can you post your entire component? What do you do with the localTodoes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all warnings should be ignored but this one can be, so just add that comment in your code and it will remove the warning for that line.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify([]));
    } else {
      let localTodos = localStorage.getItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
      console.log(localTodos);
    }
 // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

It  is due to use todos in your useEffect code and just a warning that you can ignore it or add it to the dependency and use  an if statement

```
useEffect(() => {
if (your condition to run this code once){
    if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify([]));
    } else {
      let localTodos = localStorage.getItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
      console.log(localTodos);
    }
}
  }, [todos]);
```

Comment: can I do anything to remove that warning ? I'm so freak of those things

Comment: Include it and use an if statement to check if todods needs to ve updated or not

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it

Comment: As OP writes he doesn't it to trigger every time todos changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom useLocalStorage hook. Which works like useState but it will get its initial state from local storage if the provided local storage key exists.

https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/